# What are the research areas in differential geometry involving Lie Groups action?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I love Lie groups actions! My contact with this topic occurred in the context of differentiable manifolds and riemannian geometry courses, and while studying Klein geometries. My knowledge is still very limited, though.

I would like to specialize on a research area in which I could work a lot with Lie groups action from a geometric point of view. It would be very nice if I could find some suggestions/possibilities here. I'm not connected to the university now and I couldn't find pithy information on the internet.

Thank you all, in advance.

Comment: You can try searching around on the arxiv. Google scholar is a very useful tool for doing so: here I've set a search for arxiv papers containing "lie groups" https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C7&q=lie+groups+site%3Aarxiv.org&btnG= ... if you have a favorite book or paper, take a look at papers that cited it ('cited by' in google scholar).

Comment: Good idea. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Another place you can look for research related questions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/lie-groups?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers&edited=true -- especially try sorting by votes, unanswered, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The geometry of "highly symmetric" spaces can frequently be framed almost entirely in terms of Lie groups, by studying the symmetry groups rather than the spaces themselves. See for instance the study of Riemannian space forms or symmetric spaces, which have been (partially) classified using the theory of Lie groups and their representations.

I'm not sure where the cutting edge of these fields lie, but there are certainly open problems which have a very Lie-theoretic flavor.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One example: the [representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_of_a_Lie_group#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20theoretical%20physics,group%20on%20a%20vector%20space.&text=A%20great%20deal%20is%20known,infinitesimal%27%20representations%20of%20Lie%20algebras.) of Lie groups is a large and classic area of mathematics.

Comment: Is representation theory an area of differential geometry? Isn't it from algebra?

Comment: It is not a subarea of anything. It is big and wide - from physics to number theory.It does intersect differential geometry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert, but I think ergodic theory and dynamical systems might be an interesting general direction to consider.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but I think both areas you cited deal more with differential equations / Analysis than Lie groups / Geometry. Am I wrong?

Comment: Abstractly, once could think of dynamics (in certain contexts) as studying how spaces behave under group actions (or semi-group actions). For instance, you can think of a differential equation as a time group (specifically, a Lie group) which acts on a space to induce a flow. Another example is looking at the actions of Lie groups of matrices which act on spaces of lattices (which is related to homogeneous dynamics), or the action of a Lie group of isometries on the hyperbolic plane - both are very geometrical. There are plenty more examples - feel free to explore some of them :)

Comment: @Alice: It depends on the subarea. Homogeneous dynamics has quite a bit of geometric flavor.